# Approximation behaviour after consecutive conversions

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, approximation

I recently started learn C# and I've write a simple exercise that require to convert an input from Fahrenheit to Celsius and back again. The code is simple and this is my effort (I suppose that the user give numeric input):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class DegreeConversion
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Insert far -> ");
            float far = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            float cel = (far - 32) / 9 * 5;
            Console.WriteLine(far   " degrees Fahrenheit is "   cel   " degrees Celsius");
            float far2 = cel * 9 / 5 + 32;
            Console.WriteLine(cel   " degrees Celsius is "   far2   " degrees Fahrenheit");
        }

    }
}
```

That's run, but if I try with input **0** when I back to Fahrenheit I obtain something like -1.525879E-06.
I've thinked about an approximation error, maybe a cancellation.
I've modified a little the previus code, in particular I've changed this

```
float far2 = cel * 9 / 5 + 32;
```

to this

```
float far2 = cel * 9 / 5;
float newFar = far2 + 32;
```

and now the output is 0!

I suppose that this behaviour is relative to the c# compiler, that rearranged code for better performance.
I think the first code should implement all the operation in CPU register, while the second code save them in memory. 
Am I correct?
Can you explain what's happen and how approximation work in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues here:

1. `float`, or [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) to give it its full name is a single precision floating point number. This means its precision is very limited. Many operations will lead to slight rounding errors (such as your -1.525879E-06: which is just over one part in a million).

   The first thing to do is switch to `double` (or [`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx)). This is the default
   floating point type unless you specify otherwise.

   The second thing to do is understand (and accept) the limited precision inherent in floating point
   representation. (Eg. one never compares two floating point numbers directly for equality, rather 
   check that the absolute difference is less than some small value, "epsilon":
   `Math.Abs(a - b) < epsilon`  where epsilon is dependent on the scale of `a` and `b`.)

   Finally read *[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)*.
2. `9/5` (and similar) will be performed as integers (ie. rounded down) because none of the values
   involved are not integers. Try (`9.0 / 5.0`). (Strictly because this is part of a larger expression that type of the first term will set the type (your `cel`), however it adds cality code code to make it clear that these operations are floating point and not integral.)

Comment: Your second point is incorrect. He's doing `float far2 = cel * 9 / 5 + 32;` and `cel` is a float, so the calculation will be promoted to float. However, it would certainly be clearer to specify them as doubles.

Comment: @MatthewWatson correct. However I'm skipping many details and avoiding getting too pedantic. From a code is documentation, and defensive programming view far better to use double literals here rather than having to remember whether C#'s division and multiplication are performs left or rightwards. However I will clarify...

Comment: Then you should change "because" to "if" in your point 2, because at the moment it is untrue (even after your edit) since there *is* a float involved in the expression.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Read it again: the expression I am talking about is `9 / 5` (and nothing more). I'm trying to explain to a learner, this involves something simplification.

Comment: But it's factually incorrect in the context of the OP's code. The expression 9/5 simply does not occur in isolation in the OP's code. You say "try 9.0/5.0", but this will not have any effect on the OP's code, (apart from causing a compile error unless he changes the type of `cel` to double), so this is going to be a bit perplexing.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Indeed. But that's not the point. the point is mixing different types of literals can lead to unexpected results and unclear code. Hence I quote out of context and have added a clarification as to why I deliberately did that. Summary: the statement is correct in its self, but plays a little loose in context to make a more general point. Remember "I recently started learn C#…".

Comment: Well I still think that saying "try (9.0/5.0)" when you know it won't have any effect isn't really the right thing to say without further clarification. Anyway, that's all I'm going to say. :)

Comment: Nevertheless, it's explanitory enough for a +1 ;)

Comment: @Richard I understand what you're saying about rounding, but I still have a doubt. Why, if I do `float far2 = cel * 9 / 5 + 32;` in "one line" I obtain 1.525879E-06, and if I split that in two operation like `float far2 = cel * 9 / 5; far2 = far2 + 32`I obtain 0? Maybe you've just answered, but I've not understand this. Anyway thanks for your help for now!

Comment: @GabrieleBenvenuti: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point. The two cases are different because rounding takes place differently; this is because the CPU is performing operations with its extended-precision registers, but then at the end of expressions it is rounded to the specified type. Thus breaking up the calculation differently gives different results. You can also see differences by changing optimiser settings. Dealing with floating point at this level is *hard*.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a rounding error, which you will often get when using floating point calculations. It is a result of the fact that some numbers cannot be accurately represented in binary (think of a recurring number such as 1/3 = 0.333333 etc).

To fix this:

1. Use a more accurate numeric type such as `double` or `decimal` instead of float.
2. Even after doing that, you will want to limit the number of decimal places that you display.

To limit the number of decimal places you can specify how many to display in a `ToString()`:

```
string numberToDisplay = far.ToString("n2"); 
// The "n2" means "format with 2 decimal places"
```